# Travelling as Tri-Citizen (3 passports).

Tags: passports

I have citizenship for Australia, UK & Ireland, and possess a passport for each and am planning a trip for this year. Please can you help me understand the best way to travel on these if I'm travelling from Sydney to London to Dublin, then Amsterdam, London, Sydney. It's a little complicated and I'm tempted to simply travel on my AU passport only as that's where I live and my other two passports are currently blank.

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Will this trip be entirely before, entirely after, or contain March 29th (Brexit day)? See this answer for the principles to apply: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel

Answer (score 2):

Rules in order of priority:

1. To the authorities of a country whose passport you hold, show that passport.
2. To the authorities of closely associated countries, show the closely associated passport (for you this means use the Australian passport in New Zealand, and the Irish passport in EU countries other than the UK).
3. To the authorities of any foreign country, if there is passport inspection on exit, show the passport you used to enter the country.
4. When you check in for a flight, show the passport you will use at your destination.  If that passport should have a visa in it because of transit or the duration of your stay, also show the other passport that excuses you from the visa requirement.

For simplicity, you can treat the UK as a non-EU country in applying these rules, but even after the UK leaves the EU, Irish citizens will have the right to settle in the UK as they have had since the 1920s.  You could therefore dispense with the UK passport and use the Irish and Australian passports only.